# How to create project specific file templates in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide, file-templates

I want to have project-specific templates. Like if I am working on Project 1. Only Project 1 related templates should be used. And If I am working on Project 2 Only Project 2 related templates should be used. And It would be really great if that could in their respective repositories only. So that they can be easily shared.

Answer (score 0):

**Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Template**

now find **Schema:** at top. change your schema and add new template to project schema.

After that what ever **Schema** you have selected you can see only that templates

Comment: Is there a way that they can be loaded automatically. So, we don't need to load all the templates one by one.